# How to make inline formulas look more compact?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I have something published by IEEE. I noticed that with the PDF generated by myself (top picture), some inline vectors look not as compact as in the PDF version produced by IEEE (bottom picture). The comparison is as follows. My question is, in general (it could be `IEEEtran` class, `book` class, or something else), how to make those inline math look more compact? What package or options should I use to achieve a similar result?

[image]

[image]

This is the code for producing those lines:

```
columns of $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}$ identical and its rank is reduced to 2,
with the null space of $\left\{ \left[\begin{array}{ccc} -1/\sqrt{2} & 0 &
      1/\sqrt{2}\end{array}\right]^{\text{T}}\right\}$. The other part of the
condition shows that for an $\boldsymbol{\mathbf{N}}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
    N_{1} & N_{2} & N_{3}\end{array}\right]^{\text{T}}$ in
$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}$ null space to be a reasonable solution, $N_{1}=N_{3}$
must be satisfied.
```

Comment: Obviously the `\left` and `\right` are adding a lot of space for one thing

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the braces should go in the first instance. Anyway, inline math with `\left` and `\right` will usually disrupt the interline spacing. I suggest using simply `[...]`.

I also suggest a few improvements:

1. instead of the clumsy `\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}` you can define a new command, `\bcal`;
2. using `matrix` instead of `array` will remove the sidebearings from the array;
3. `\text{T}` for the transpose would give bad results in case the text is in a theorem statement, better using `\mathrm` (inside a semantic command).

Note also that `\boldsymbol{\mathbf{N}}` does nothing different from `\mathbf{N}`.

The vinculum of the square root would clash with the bracket, so I recommend `\,` for inserting a thin space.

I suggest two realizations for `\rowvector`: one with the default intercolumn space, one with half of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newcommand{\bcal}[1]{\bm{\mathcal{#1}}}
\newcommand{\transpose}{^{\mathrm{T}}}

\newcommand{\rowvector}[1]{[\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}]}

\begin{document}

\noindent % just for this example
columns of $\bcal{A}$ identical and its rank is reduced to~$2$, with the null 
space of $\rowvector{-1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2}\,}\transpose$.
The other part of the condition shows that for an 
$\mathbf{N}=\rowvector{N_{1} & N_{2} & N_{3}}\transpose$ in
$\bcal{A}$ null space to be a reasonable solution, $N_{1}=N_{3}$
must be satisfied.

\bigskip

% for the second example
\renewcommand{\rowvector}[1]{%
  [\begingroup
  \setlength\arraycolsep{0.5\arraycolsep}%
  \begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}%
  \endgroup]
}


\noindent % just for this example
columns of $\bcal{A}$ identical and its rank is reduced to~$2$, with the null 
space of $\rowvector{-1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2}\,}\transpose$.
The other part of the condition shows that for an 
$\mathbf{N}=\rowvector{N_{1} & N_{2} & N_{3}}\transpose$ in
$\bcal{A}$ null space to be a reasonable solution, $N_{1}=N_{3}$
must be satisfied.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As better alternatives to `\boldsymbol{\mathcal{...}}`, `mathalpha` defines `\mathbcal` and `unicode-math` defines `\mathbfcal` or `\symbfcal`.

Answer (score 0):

do not use `\left` and `\right` and no `array`:

```
columns of $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}$ identical and its rank is reduced to 2, with the null space 
of $\{ [-1/\sqrt{2} 0 1/\sqrt{2}]^{\text{T}}\}$. The other part of the condition 
shows that for an $\mathbf{N}=[N_{1} N_{2} N_{3}]^{\text{T}}$ 
in $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}$ null space to be 
a reasonable solution, $N_{1}=N_{3}$ must be satisfied.
```

[image]

If you want some space between the elements write `N_1\, N_2,...`

Comment: Somehow I checked their webpage version and it seems that the code they are using are the same as mine. They seem to have used `\left` `\right` and `array` so I was wondering if they use some additional package.

Comment: You're short some space between elements within the vector...

Answer (score 0):

In math mode there are plenty of options. The relevant one here might be `\!`  (bang-escape a space).

Overleaf has a [great resource on the topic](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode). Here is an extract from their excellent page:

```
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= x^2\! +3x\! +2 \\
f(x) &= x^2+3x+2 \\
f(x) &= x^2\, +3x\, +2 \\
f(x) &= x^2\: +3x\: +2 \\
f(x) &= x^2\; +3x\; +2 \\
f(x) &= x^2\ +3x\ +2 \\
f(x) &= x^2\quad +3x\quad +2 \\
f(x) &= x^2\qquad +3x\qquad +2
\end{align*}
```

The rendering shows how the different options finely tunes spacing (result available at the linked page).